# nslookup outputs SERVFAIL error from configured local DNS

Tags: ubuntu, docker, configuration, dns, systemd-resolved

I was watching a YouTube tutorial on configuring Nginx and local DNS settings. As I followed along on my Ubuntu 22.04 host machine, I ran into an issue with the DNS server I had set up with Docker per the tutorial instructions. When I tried to resolve a domain name I had entered, the Docker DNS server could not resolve it.

**nslookup ns.main.com**

```
;; Got SERVFAIL reply from 127.0.0.1, trying next server
Server:         192.168.1.1
Address:        192.168.1.1#53

** server can't find ns.main.com: NXDOMAIN
```

The first issue I encountered was being able to successfully build the Docker containers using docker-compose, but then getting an error when trying to start them up with docker-compose up. The error indicated that port 53 was already in use by systemd-resolved on my Ubuntu host. I was able to resolve this conflict and get the containers running by following the steps outlined in [Ubuntu: How To Free Up Port 53, Used By systemd-resolved](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2020/07/ubuntu-how-to-free-up-port-53-used-by.html) which helped release port 53 from systemd-resolved.

**/etc/resolv.conf**

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver fe80::1%3
search .
```

**sudo lsof -i :53**

```
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
com.docke 4079 juan  372u  IPv6 116841      0t0  UDP *:domain
```

I was searching online for solutions to my DNS resolution problem, but I'm still unsure of the correct approach. Some information indicates that IPv6 may be causing the issues and that I should avoid using it, but I don't know if that's the right move. I'm not certain what the root cause of my DNS troubles is - whether it's an IPv6 compatibility problem, a misconfiguration, or something else.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
services:
  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./nginx/
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/html/:/usr/share/nginx/html/
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
  dns:
    build:
      context: ./dns/
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 53:53
      - 53:53/udp
    volumes:
      - ./dns/named.conf:/etc/bind/named.conf
      - ./dns/zone/:/etc/bind/zone/
    command: named -c /etc/bind/named.conf -g -u named
```

**dns/Dockerfile**

```
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk add bind openrc
RUN rc-update -u named
```

**dns/named.conf**

```
options {
    directory "var/bind";
    allow-transfer { "none"; };
    allow-query { any; };
    listen-on { any; };
};

zone "main.com" IN {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zone/main.com";
};
```

**dns/zone/main.com**

```
$ttl 86400
@       IN      SOA ns.main.com.    hostmaster.main.com.(
                    202 ; Serial
                    600 ; Refresh
                    3600 ; Retry
                    12378237) ; Expire

@       IN      NS  ns.main.com.
ns      IN      A   127.0.0.1
```

**nginx/conf.d/default.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ns.main.com;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/main;
        index index.html;
    }
}
```

**nginx/Dockerfile**

```
FROM nginx:latest
COPY ./html /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y procps
```